# RememberMe option in an asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, remember-me

Hai guys,

- what are the possible ways of implementing remember me option in an asp.net web application?
  [alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/0f9ebba1bb.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/0f9ebba1bb.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Forms Authentication, just pass `true` as a second argument to [RedirectFromLoginPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx).

Otherwise, idea is essentially the same: you need to create a so-called "[persistent cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)", which means that you have to specify correct cookie expiration date.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Request.Cookies["myCookie"] != null)
                {
                    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("myCookie");
                    txtUserName.Text = cookie.Values["username"];
                    txtPassword.Attributes.Add("value", cookie.Values["password"]);



                }
            }

        }
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 bool IsRemember = chkRememberMe.Checked;
                    if (IsRemember)
                    {
                        myCookie.Values.Add("username", txtUserName.Text);
                        myCookie.Values.Add("password", txtPassword.Text);
                        myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myCookie.Values.Add("username", string.Empty);
                        myCookie.Values.Add("password", string.Empty);
                        myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
                    }
 Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

Comment: This solution, however, will save the users password in cleartext on his/her computer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [How to: Create an ASP.NET Login Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178331.aspx)

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" 
           runat="server" 
           DestinationPageUrl="~/MembersHome.aspx">
</asp:Login>
```